# GEE, name automaticaly an image to export to drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

I would like to create a function so that my image description has the date im using to filter my image collection.

```
var BURNED = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD64A1")
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-08-01','2019-08-31'))

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: BURNED,
  description: 'BURN_2019-08-01_2019-08-31',
  maxPixels: 10e11,
  folder: 'Burned Areas'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for `ee.Filter.date`. You can also use string concatenation to make your description. You can put all that within a function and then call it with the dates you want. Putting it all together:

```js
function export_date_range(date_start, date_end){
  var BURNED = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD64A1")
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date(date_start,date_end));
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: BURNED,
    description: 'BURN_'+date_start+'_'+date_end,
    maxPixels: 10e11,
    folder: 'Burned Areas'
  });
}

export_date_range("2019-08-01","2019-08-31");
```

Comment: You can also use **.filterDate(date_start,date_end)** instead of **.filter(ee.Filter.date())**